# Using Jenkins for Yii Codeception tests

Tags: php, bash, shell, jenkins, yii2

I am trying to automate Yii 2 tests using Jenkins. Since the tests have been recently decentralized, I would like to see all tests run at once. For this, I have created a small shell script

***test-all.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
which codecept
for i in */tests
do
    i=${i%tests}
    cd "$i"
    codecept run --fail-fast
    cd ../
done
```

When this is run from the command-line (Git Bash), the tests run properly. However, when I run this file in Jenkins, although the build returns SUCCESSfully, no tests are being run.

```
[CI] $ "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe" -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson8239762865441374376.sh
+ cd /c/xampp/htdocs/mtnt-2
+ /usr/bin/bash test-all.sh
/c/xampp/htdocs/mtnt-2
test-all.sh: line 3: which: command not found
test-all.sh: line 8: codecept: command not found
test-all.sh: line 8: codecept: command not found
test-all.sh: line 8: codecept: command not found
test-all.sh: line 8: codecept: command not found
Finished: SUCCESS
```

It can't seem to find the `which` command and the `codecept` command which are both in my `PATH` variable.

How do I fix this?

#### Updates

So far, I have attempted changing the path for the master node. That also didn't suffice. I confirmed through `Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> System Information` that the path to the global Composer vendor bin is included in the Path variable.

I also tried having `codeception` locally in the project. The new test-all.sh script is thus

```
#!/bin/bash
ROOT_FOLDER=`pwd`
for i in */tests
do
    i=${i%tests}
    cd "`pwd`/$i"
    $ROOT_FOLDER/vendor/bin/codecept run --fail-fast
    cd ../
done
```

Now, I get the following error.

```
[CI] $ "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe" -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson2613836971033972638.sh
+ cd /c/xampp/htdocs/mtnt-2/
+ ./test-all.sh
/usr/bin/env: sh: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: sh: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: sh: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: sh: No such file or directory
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Funny. You are trying to run bash command under windows? Do you realize this?

Comment: @BogdanBurim please let's not be condescending (: I have used the `Execute Windows Batch Command` option but it did not work out. I have included `Git Bash` as my _default shell_ in Jenkins and that's what it uses, from the first line.